# DocuSign - Collaboration/ Share Fields

Tags: docusignapi

I am receiving the error-code "REQUIRE_ALL_SHARED_TAB_NOT_ENABLED", when I try to create a field with the collaboration/share feature.
The message says I that "allow shared tabs is not enabled", but I can not find the setting on the DocuSign admin page neither in the new nor in the classic page. 
Where can I enable this setting?

This is the JSON response:

```
"emailTabs": [
{
  "shared": "true",
  "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "true",
  "requireAll": "true",
  "name": "emailaddress1",
  "value": "Type your email here",
  "width": 188,
  "required": "true",
  "locked": "false",
  "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
  "disableAutoSize": "true",
  "maxLength": 4000,
  "tabLabel": "\\*emailaddress1",
  "font": "arial",
  "bold": "false",
  "italic": "false",
  "underline": "false",
  "fontColor": "black",
  "fontSize": "size7",
  "documentId": "1",
  "recipientId": "cfa81ae2-466d-408c-9df6-80a320091713",
  "pageNumber": "1",
  "xPosition": "164",
  "yPosition": "359",
  "anchorString": "!!emailaddress1",
  "anchorXOffset": "0",
  "anchorYOffset": "0",
  "tabId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "errorDetails": {
    "errorCode": "REQUIRE_ALL_SHARED_TAB_NOT_ENABLED",
    "message": "Allow Shared Tabs is not enabled on account."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [UpdateAccountSettings](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Accounts/Accounts/updateSettings/) api to enable the "**Allow Shared Tabs**" account setting

> PUT /v2/accounts/{accountId}/settings

```
{
 "accountSettings": [
    {
        "name": "allowSharedTabs",
        "value": "true"
    }
 ]
}
```

Comment: So the only way to enable this is via api? Is there no option on the admin page?

Comment: There is no such option on the admin page.